# Selenium TestNG framework unable to call driver object in multiple test

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute the following program but getting a null pointer error. where @test is not able to access the object - driver. what could be the possible error i am making. Error -

JavaScript warning: https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en_US.MHBUsB8Me90.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,qsm,d,csi/am=wCJGjhccAPk_IRQStxAWyAImDiA/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oGwMPBWhsFBKoM1svJAFUVoVQRQug, line 7: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
FAILED: websiteTitle

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myPackage.TestNGforHDFC.websiteTitle(TestNGforHDFC.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)

package myPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNGforHDFC {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String urlUnderTest = "http://www.google.com";
    public String projLocation = "C:\\Users\\Nikita Agrawal\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe";
    @BeforeTest
    public void login()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", projLocation);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(urlUnderTest);
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }

    @Test
public void websiteTitle()
    {
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class variable `driver` is never initialized, you're defining a new variable called `driver` inside the `login` method.

Use:

```
public void login(){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    ....
}
```

Instead of:

```
public void login(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    ....
}
```

Comment: @NileshKhoriya I'm glad I could help. If this solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer.